# Could I hit 10,000 simultaneous connections with Play2?

Tags: playframework

- Database-Driven App
- MongoDB + Solr
- Collaborative
- Real time push notifications

Comment: I seriously doubt if any web framework will let you do that on the single machine. Probably it's possible with advanced scenario however... your question is too generic to guessing what do you need.

Comment: this is the best question ever.

Comment: one of the good things with play is that since it is stateless on the font server, you can serve it with tons of machines. it is rather up to your database. also, what kind of question is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's could be possible with minding some things:

1. Use asynchronous DB drivers, like Reactive Mongo. Don't block server awaiting result. Look into Enumerator/Iteratee pattern to reduce memory usage.
2. Don't block your web workers. Use AsyncResult within your controllers.
3. Call SOLR asynchronously too [Call Solr asynchronous from Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270393/call-solr-asynchronous-from-play-framework)
4. Play is stateless framework. Don't make an app stateful by yourself, and you can scale it easily by just adding servers/cloud instances.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with enough memory and CPUs on a single machine since Play uses Netty (Java NIO) under the covers.  You probably should check out the [Reactive Mongo Play Plugin](https://github.com/zenexity/Play-ReactiveMongo) to take advantage of NIO in the Mongo connections.