# Call Solr asynchronous from Play Framework

Tags: scala, solr, playframework, playframework-2.1, solrj

I have created a Play 2.1 Scala application. I am uncertain what's the best way to call Solr from a Play application:

- There is no Solr module for Play 2.
- AFAIK all Solr-APIs like SolrJ are blocking.
- I could wrap a SolrJ call into a `Future`, but this will also block a thread, correct?
- Should I use the `play.api.libs.ws.WS` library to call Solr and use Plays JSON support to extract the result (like in the example below) or is there any easier/faster way?

  ```
  val solrQuery: Future[play.api.libs.ws.Response] = WS.url("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=id%3A123&wt=json").get()
  ```

Comment: You could consider using either Dispatch or Spray as both are built on top of Netty and are fully NIO when making http requests.

Comment: Thanks, but why would Dispatch or Spray be better for that than the Webservice library `WS` from Play?

Comment: I'm not sure what the play ws api is doing under the hood. Even though its returning a future I wasn't sure if it still was doing blocking io when making the http call. I would look into that and if its nio then probably a good choice if you already are using play. If not then you could look into the libs I mentioned.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to create a solrj-play lib that uses WS under the hood and provides a solrj like api (for query and types)? I'd find this also useful :-)

Comment: Ok, WS is not blocking, so I think I will use WS.

Comment: [Solr-scala-client](https://github.com/takezoe/solr-scala-client) has started a branch with async Solr calls now (see [Issue 9](https://github.com/takezoe/solr-scala-client/issues/9#issuecomment-20275191)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I use WS in my side project:

```
val itselfNodeFuture = Statix.doParams( Statix.SolrSelectWSReq, 
    List(
    "wt"     -> "json", 
    "q"      -> "*:*",
    "fq"     -> "node_type:collection",
    "fq"     -> "id:%d".format( nodeId),
    "indent" -> "true",
    "rows"   -> "1",
    "fl"     -> "id,parent_id,title",
    "fl"     -> "date_created,date_about,date_modified")
).get()

//Use the first Await after the last future
val itselfJson = Await.result(
    itselfNodeFuture, Duration("2 sec")).json

val mainRow = (itselfJson \ "response" \ "docs").as[ Seq[JsValue]]
val mainNodeParent = (mainRow(0) \ "parent_id").as[Long]
val mainNodeTitle = (mainRow(0) \ "title").as[String]
```

And here's the utility class I use, the `doParams` is especially useful.

```
object Statix { //Noder must extend this
    def SolrSelectWSReq = WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr-store/collection1/select/")
    def SolrUpdateWSReq = WS.url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr-store/collection1/update/json/")

    def doParams(request: WS.WSRequestHolder, params: List[(String, String)]) = {
        params.foldLeft( request){
            (wsReq, tuple) => wsReq.withQueryString( tuple)}}
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I will start a non-blocking Solr client based on WS like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You want to wrap the call in a Future with its own [Execution context](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ThreadPools). This way the call may be blocking, but it will use a different thread pool, not blocking the main application.

In fact, this is standard behaviour when facing blocking or slow tasks, like sending queries to a database or doing some heavy-lifting task.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this need recently and didn't find anything useful googling about.  Below is only for querying but could be expanded.  I'm assuming you want to stay with SolrJ classes.  The SolrQuery and QueryResponse are pretty easy to work with.

So to query.  You'll want to build up your SolrQuery as normal.  For "wt" supply "javabin".  This will give you a response in the compressed binary format that SolrJ uses internally.

```
val sq = new SolrQuery()
sq.set("wt", "javabin")
...
```

You'll want to turn your SolrQuery into something that WS understands.  (I haven't added all the imports since most are straightforward to figure out [e.g., by your IDE].  Those I have included might not be as obvious.)

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def solrQueryToForm(sq: SolrQuery): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {
  sq.getParameterNames.asScala.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Seq[String]]) {
    case (m, n) =>
      m + (n -> sq.getParams(n))
  }
}
```

In my shop we use a default collection and handler (i.e., "/select") but you'll want those to be overridden by the SolrQuery

```
def solrEndpoint(sq: SolrQuery): String = {
  val coll = sq.get("collection", defaultCollection)
  val hand = Option(sq.getRequestHandler).getOrElse(defaultHandler)
  formSolrEndpoint(solrUrl, coll, hand)
}

def formSolrEndpoint(base: String, collection: String, handler: String): String = {
  val sb = new StringBuilder(base)
  if (sb.last != '/') sb.append('/')
  sb.append(collection)
  if (!handler.startsWith("/")) sb.append('/')
  sb.append(handler)
  sb.result()
}
```

You'll need some code to map the WSResponse to a QueryResponse

```
import com.ning.http.client.{Response => ACHResponse}

def wsResponseToQueryResponse(wsResponse: WSResponse)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): QueryResponse = {
  val jbcUnmarshal = {
    val rbis = wsResponse.underlying[ACHResponse].getResponseBodyAsStream

    try {
      new JavaBinCodec().unmarshal(rbis)
    }
    finally {
      if (rbis != null)
        rbis.close()
    }
  }

  // p1: SolrJ pulls the same cast
  // p2: We didn't use a SolrServer to chat with Solr so cannot provide it to QueryResponse
  new QueryResponse(jbcUnmarshal.asInstanceOf[NamedList[Object]], null)
}
```

And that gives you all the pieces to call Solr using Play's async WS service.

```
def query(sq: SolrQuery)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[QueryResponse] = {
  val sqstar = sq.getCopy
  sqstar.set("wt", "javabin")

  WS.url(solrEndpoint(sqstar))
    .post(solrQueryToForm(sqstar))
    .map(wsResponseToQueryResponse)
}
```

Since Play now publishes the webservice code as a standalone jar this means pretty much any project should be able to query Solr asynchronously.  Hope that's useful.

Comment: Thanks, looks good for me. I cannot test it, because in my current project I finally switched fromn Solr to Elasticsearch (with it's async API).