# How can I parse Solr Json in Play Framework?

Tags: java, php, solr, playframework, playframework-2.0

I started it all with Solrj but lately I am finding it difficult to query Solr from JAVA. And even if I am able to, I have to make queries several times. I am not sure if I am wrong here. (for instance, one query for retrieving numfound and one query for facet and so on...). Please suggest me with three questions :

1) Am I wrong in above assumption ?

2) All I want is a better control which I believe I can get with xml or Json parsing. Since I am using Play Framework with Java api, can you please suggest me good ways to read output from Solr ?

3) Also, do you think it will be a better and flexible deal if I switch from Play Framework to CodeIgniter/PHP framework ?

Comment: Heres an answer I posted on the same:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270393/call-solr-asynchronous-from-play-framework/17315047#17315047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend going through the Solr tutorial first, ignoring the play framework. It shows the basics of Solr. You should not need to make multiple queries to get counts and facet separately, as long as the search itself is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I am now exploring solr tutorial.